# Expo watchman Hot reloading not detecting code change in Docker volume

Tags: docker, react-native, expo, watchman

We are currently building a react-native app with expo inside a Docker container. This Expo-app uses watchman to handle hot reloading.

Is there a polling mechanism which constantly polls the code in a Docker volume? Currently we have to reset the application each time to view a code change live. In our experience, inside a Docker container the Expo-App doesn't detect changes, so hot reloading isn't working.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe it help knowing how you start the docker container, how you map the volumes, if you use docker-compose (and therefore how the docker-compose.yml looks like)